# What is expected response when server throws application exception like IllegalArgrumentException?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, resteasy

When I make a rest request and server throws an application exception like IllegalArgumentException, I get response with **http status 404**.

Wouldn't a response with **http status 500** be better?

Or what would actually be the expected response when an application exception is thrown? Is there some default behaviour in resteasy, spring or tomcat itself?

I know I can use an ExceptionMapper for resteasy, but is this really best practice or is there a better alternative?

I'm using following setup:

- spring
- resteasy
- tomcat 7

**Update**:

The problem I'm facing is that I have 2 web applications, one is returning http status 500 and the other is returning http status 400 when an IllegalArgumentException is thrown. I can't figure out why they behave different. It seems to me, that both web application have the same spring and resteasy configuration.

When I'm debugging, I see that resteasy is transforming the IllegalArgumentException to a org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException, but the response and the response status code, respectively, is not touched.

So besides not knowing which http status code would be the expected one (400, as Jon Skeet and Stefano Cazzola already pointed out), I didn't know either why the 2 web applications behaves different.

I couldn't find any resteasy ExceptionMapper in both web application.
So is there some default behavior in resteasy, spring or tomcat, which is mapping an IllegalArgumentException to http status 404 or http status 500? Or how can this happen?

Comment: If it's for an IllegalArgumentException, is that due to the request being invalid? If so, 400 would be the right response.

Comment: Yes, actually it is due to the request being invalid, cause some validation fails. So what would be the best way to map this exception instead of 404 to 400?

Comment: Don't know about that side - haven't used any of the technologies you've mentioned for quite a while, I'm afraid.

Comment: @sfrutig just as a wild guess, can you see any method marked as `@ExceptionHandler` or any class marked as `@ControllerAdvice`? If you do, then they are responsible for translating the `IllegalArgumentException` into a 400 error. Otherwise, can you post some code from the two webpps you mentioned?

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't have an error.jsp file, which I mentioned in web.xml (<error-page><exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> <location>/error.jsp</location></error-page>).

Answer (score 1):

The response code is correlated to the error happened in the server. If the error is related to an invalid input received from the client, then the formally correct response status is 400 (Bad Request). The difference with 500 is that returning 400 is the **correct** behaviour for the server: means, the server processed correctly and responded with  an error because the request was wrong. If the same request will ever be resubmitted, it will receive the same error response. The server is not supposed to correct this error, it is up to the client.

You can take [this link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) as a reference

Comment: Ok, thank you. I would also like to know, why I get http status 404 or http status 500. See my updated question.